# Four dimensional Bravais lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I am wondering if there are any reference on four dimensional Bravais lattice and their primitive vectors, even an example will help.

Comment: There is much better than that. Search for "4 dimensional space groups". Search for work by David Mermin on quasicrystals. That should lead you to the major citations.